# Expressions with Logical Operators - what is it equivalent to?

Tags: java, logical-operators, boolean-algebra

I have this logical operator expression:

```
!(!(a != b) && (b > 7))
```

How do you simplify it and find the equivalent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Break it down... `!(a != b)` should be easy, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others: [Demorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
!(!(a != b) && (b > 7)) // x != y --> !(x == y) 
!(!!(a == b) && (b > 7)) // !!x --> x 
!((a == b) && (b > 7)) // !(x && y) --> !x || !y
!(a == b) || !(b > 7) // !(x == y) --> x != y;; !(x > y) --> x <= y
(a != b) || (b <= 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Demorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
!(!(a != b) && (b > 7))
!!(a != b) || !(b > 7)
a != b || b <= 7
```